# Is it Possible to Run Multiple Instances of IIS 7.5 on the Same Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

I would like to know if it is possible to run multiple instances of IIS 7.5 on one operating system. My department is looking at taking our virtual environment that currently has separate development, QA and production servers (each with their own Windows Server O/S of course) and combining the those resources into a singled clustered environment. However, we would still like the ability to isolate the environments from each other by creating separate IIS instances but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Virtualization provides for so much flexibility in terms of VM deployment, cloning, templates, differencing disks, snapshots, etc. that I'm at a loss to understand why they would want to combine the DEV, QA and PROD environments on the same virtual machine. What's the reasoning behind wanting to combine them?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot. You can, of course, have multiple sites that have multiple URLs with their own application pools. But you cannot actually run multiple instances.

I'd really recommend keeping your QA and Test environments off of your production boxes wherever possible. You don't really want a runaway process from some dev code to lock up your whole server if it's running your production website, do you? That's the reason for separate environments in the first place.

Comment: +1 Each application pool will run inside its own `w3wp.exe` process so you'll at least prevent separate apps from trashing another's process if you put them in separate pools. But yeah, separate servers is the best plan.